# "fought in the World War II" versus "fought in the second World War"

Tags: word-usage, definite-articles, expression-choice

Why is

> fought in the second World War

or

> fought in the Vietnam War

correct but

> fought in the World War II

is not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is similar to the following example:

> performed in the film

and

> performed in the "Ted".

That one should not have the *"the"*:

> performed in "Ted".

*"Second World War"* is not it's name, it is more describing what it was - *"the second war that involved the world"*, in the same way that *"film"* is not it's name, it is describing what it is. The name is *"World War II"* and *"Ted"*

The Vietnam war:

Vietnam War has a second name - Second Indochina War. Both of these use *"the "*. However, if it was called the *"Indochina War II"*, it wouldn't use *"the"*.

Comment: Does that work with _Vietnam War_ or it's other name _Second Indochina War_?

Comment: No, both of those use the

Comment: Might be worth adding something about that, as the author did ask about the _the_ in the Vietnam War as well.

Comment: @Tim. I do not agree that 'the name is World War II' as you state. *World War I* and *World War II* reflect American parlance. Usually in Britain we say *the First World War* and *the Second World War*

Comment: I'm in England. I say World War II, although have no objections to second world war.

Comment: _Second World War_ is just as much a name as _World War II_ is. The only difference is that articles are not allowed before noun phrases that have _(number) [X]_ in them (where _[X]_ is any number). Similarly, the phrase is “What's behind door number three?”, not “What's behind the door number three?”. This goes for names and non-names alike.

Answer (score 4):

Key point here:

> The *second*

Vs:

> The *II*

*Second* is an adjective; *II* is not!

Answer (score -4):

Second Word War is the Proper way in American English to write World War II using Ordinal Numbers.  Roman Numerals on the other hand do not have an ordinal equivalent.  See [Vaibhav Garg's answer in this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1587/using-the-before-ordinal-numbers).