# use of "the" for dates

Tags: word-usage, articles

Is it fine to write

> during the second half **of 4th** century B.C.

or is it preferable to write

> during the second half of **the 4th** century B.C.

Comment: I much prefer the second one. However Americans have a tendency to drop the definite article with dates, and they may find it acceptable.

Comment: @WS2 I don't think it's a matter of opinion or personal style but an omission on part of certain authors for whatever reason. The definite article is grammatically required.

Comment: @Kris But Americans do say things like "It's happening on July fourteen". In Britain it is "...on the fourteenth of July", or if we are already in July "...on the fourteenth".

Comment: @WS2 The first is not acceptable to me as an American (but not a historian).

Answer (score 1):

This question was already answered here.

the case being: ordinal numbers as adjectives, as with your inquiry.

[Using "the" before ordinal numbers](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1587/using-the-before-ordinal-numbers)

you may also find your answer in this exercise, the answers are pretty well detailed.

https://www.adelaide.edu.au/english-for-uni/articles/articles_exercises_english_for_uni.pdf